# Nested dictionaries in pyarrow

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyarrow

I have been trying to test out pyarrow, and I have been having issues with converting nested dictionaries to Tables. When I run this code:

```
import pyarrow as pa

a = {'a':{'b':[1,2,3], 'c':[3,2,1], 'd':[2,3,1]}}
schema = pa.schema([pa.field('a', pa.struct([pa.field('b', pa.int32()), pa.field('c', pa.int32()), pa.field('d', pa.int32())]))])

pa_a = pa.Table.from_pydict(a, schema)
```

I get back `pyarrow.lib.ArrowTypeError: Could not convert b with type str: was expecting tuple of (key, value) pair`

Which seems weird, should the schema complain if it's not valid, or what am I missing here? Is there no way to convert nested dictionaries?

Answer (score 0):

If all your column values live within the arrays `b`, `c` and `d` then you can simply do:

```py
pa_a = pa.Table.from_pydict(
    a['a'],
    pa.schema([
        pa.field('b', pa.int32()),
        pa.field('c', pa.int32()),
        pa.field('d', pa.int32()),
    ]),
)

print(pa_a)
#    b  c  d
# 0  1  3  2
# 1  2  2  3
# 2  3  1  1
```